# Assert "id < 0" failed in Qt ActiveX

Tags: c++, qt, com, activex

I make a program using Microsoft Access 2010 ActiveX (COM) to display references of a project (.adp file):

```
Access::Application* app = new Access::Application(nullptr);
app->SetVisible(true);

app->OpenAccessProject("E:\\solulog_dev\\SoluTools\\app\\test\\sources\\utilitaires\\liste_aide.adp", true);

int nb_ref = app->References()->Count();
qDebug().nospace() << nb_ref << " references";

for(int ref_num = 1; ref_num <= nb_ref; ref_num++)
{
    Access::Reference* ref = app->References()->Item(ref_num);
    qDebug().nospace() << "Reference #" << ref_num << " : " << ref->Name() << " (" << ref->Guid() << ") : " << ref->FullPath();
}

app->CloseCurrentDatabase();
app->Quit();
```

But at execution, I get the right number of references (5 in this case), but *any* call to *any* property of *any* reference get the same error:

> Debug Error!
>
> Program: c:\Qt\5.11.1\msvc2015\bin\Qt5Cored.dll
>
> Module: 5.11.1
>   File: qaxbase.cpp
>   Line: 3763
>
> ASSERT: "id < 0" in file qaxbase.cpp, line 3763

It seems to failed when try accessing property through QMetaObject.

I also get a warning followed by an error on each call to "References" object. The code works (I get the right number of references), but maybe it's related:

> CoCreateInstance failure (Classe non enregistrée)
>   QAxBase::setControl: requested control {eb106214-9c89-11cf-a2b3-00a0c90542ff} could not be instantiated

This CLSID is correctly registered and reference "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ReferencesClass" as expected

Anyone can help me with this assert ?

Comment: Check the Access component is registered with the same bitness as your program (32-bit vs 64-bit registry)

Comment: Already checked, the CLSID is registered both in 32 and 64 bits registry. And like I said, the "app->References()->count()" works very well as like the "Item(...)" call for each reference

Comment: And yet the error from CoCreateInstance tells us the the CLSID eb106214-9c89-11cf-a2b3-00a0c90542ff is not registered. "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ReferencesClass" in a .NET thing, not a "pure" Access thing, is this normal? Why do you use .NET? You can use a tool like procmon from sysinternals to check what registry paths are used by your app.

Comment: I don't know ActiveX / COM internal. This is what I get in RegEdit (key path : HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EB106214-9C89-11CF-A2B3-00A0C90542FF}\InprocServer32\14.0.0.0) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sywNY.png

Comment: If you'running on a 64-bit OS, this is the 64-bit registry only (plus why do you reference a .NET interop class?)

Comment: I'm on a 32-bit server, so this is a 32-bit registry. And on test server (which is 64-bit), i've the same thing in 64-bit registry.

I don't *want* reference a .NET interop : i just call "app->References()" (part of official Access COM) and then i get an error talking about {EB106214-9C89-11CF-A2B3-00A0C90542FF} CLSID, i don't know anymore.

Comment: If your program is 32-bit running on a 64-bit machine, you must check the 32-bit registry (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node etc.), not the 64-registry. http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2010/02/03/32-bit-applications-on-64-bit-windows-welcome-wow6432node-registry-key/

Comment: OK, also find in Wow6432Node with exact same values : https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1swL.png

Answer (score 0):

I tried the exact same code but using QAxObject directly, not through C++ namespace generated using dumpcpp :

```
QAxObject* app = new QAxObject("Access.Application", nullptr);
app->setProperty("Visible", true);

app->dynamicCall("OpenAccessProject(QString, bool)", "E:\\solulog_dev\\SoluTools\\app\\test\\sources\\utilitaires\\liste_aide.adp");

QAxObject* references = app->querySubObject("References");

int nb_ref = references->property("Count").toInt();
qDebug().nospace() << nb_ref << " références";

for(int ref_num = 1; ref_num <= nb_ref; ref_num++)
{
    QAxObject* reference = references->querySubObject("Item(QVariant)", ref_num);
    qDebug().nospace() << "Reference #" << ref_num << " : " << reference->property("Name").toString() << " (" << reference->property("Guid").toString() << ") : " << reference->property("FullPath").toString();
}

app->dynamicCall("CloseCurrentDatabase()");
app->dynamicCall("Quit()");
delete app;
```

And this time, all works perfectly. Not error about bad instantiation and I get values for each reference... So I presume it is a dumpcpp error. Should I report this problem to Qt ?